Dnd Kit + Re-Resizable not working as expected
I have a react project where I am trying to build sort of a figma like app. I already added zoom, panning and dragging using DnDKit, and now I am trying to implement re-resizable. The Draggable component is the one that wraps the Resizable component, but even though I see the resize handles on the UI, the events on the Resizable component are not being triggered.
This is the code for the rendering of the Draggable component.
<div
      {...listeners}
      {...attributes}
      ref={setNodeRef}
      className="draggable"
      style={{
        width,
        height,
        top: y,
        left: x,
        position: "absolute",
        backgroundColor: "white",
        border: `1px solid ${activeElement === id ? "#0984e3" : "black"}`,
        transform: transform
          ? `translate3d(${transform.x}px, ${transform.y}px, 0)`
          : undefined,
      }}
      onPointerDown={(e) => {
        setActiveElement(id);

        if (listeners && listeners.onPointerDown) {
          listeners.onPointerDown(e);
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
        }
      }}
    >
      <Resizable
        size={{ width, height }}
        onResize={() => console.log("on resize")}
        onResizeStart={(e) => {
          console.log(e);
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          console.log("resize");
        }}
        onResizeStop={(e, direction, ref, delta) => {
          console.log("on resize stop");
        }}
      ></Resizable>
    </div>

I am trying to achieve dragging and resizing of elements. I know that there is a problem that requires to stop the listeners of Dndkit to avoid dragging and resizing at the same time, but that would be the next step. For now I am not even able to achieve the dragging and resizing at the same time, cause the events on the Resizable component are not being trigger.
